Trying to late bind outlook to but getting type mismatch error after create object line
I am trying to late bind the process of opening up an outlook message for reporting a problem or a suggestion for a spreadsheet.  I am trying to prefill the TO: and CC: recipients, Subject Line, and the first couple of lines of the the message body.  I do not want to send the message as I need the user to populate the message body with their thoughts.
I found some code that was originally set up using early binding.  Then I proceeded to mangle it to hopefully suit my needs.  Then I butchered it trying to make it work with late binding.
When I step through the code, I get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch in the second create object line which I am assuming is actually trying to create the message.  I tried changing the olMailItem to 0. This results in an activeX error:  Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.
I have Option Explicit set.
Private Sub ReportBug_Click()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim objOutlookRecip As Object
Dim olMailItem As Object
Dim Recipients As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateObject(olMailItem)
    
    With objOutlookMsg
        Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
        'Set TO: recipient
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("username@domain.com")
        objOutlookRecip.Type = 1 '1 for to
        'Set CC: recipient
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Username2@Domain.com")
        objOutlookRecip.Type = 2 '2 for cc
    
        'Set Subject Line
        .Subject = "Forecasting Sheet Bug / Recommendation from " & Me.Cells(4, 2).Value
        'start message body
        .HTMLBody = "To whom it may concern," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "With respect to the forecasting sheet I noted the following:" & vbCrLf
        
        'Resolve each Recipient's name.
        For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
          objOutlookRecip.Resolve
        Next
        
        'objOutlookMsg.Send
        .Display
        
    End With
        
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Some of the previous questions I looked at were:
This one where I learned to switch out olTO and olCC with their numeric values.  I could not find a numeric value listed for olMailItem.
And This one which made oMail.CC = "email address here" look like a simpler option
And this one where I snagged the initial starting code for me
And I swear there was another which I can no longer find the link for.
Questions
How do I fix my goofS and get rid of the error?

When try Outlook automation from a different application, the constants values may not  mean anything. So, try Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6). 6 = constant olFolderInbox value...

Change this:
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateObject(olMailItem)

to this:
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


Not sure if I need to ask a new question or not but the .HTMLBody = "To whom it may concern," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "With respect to the forecasting sheet I noted the following:" & vbCrLf is coming through as a single line and ignoring the carriage returns.

You're not using HTML so just use the Body property.
